# Hide blue box around code during slideshow of a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, hide, slideshow, rise

I am preparing a presentation in Jupyter Notebook (version 6.1.4, not Lab)

[image: example]

(not the final notebook, just an example)
I also hide the code through a nbextension.

When I go into the slideshow (RISE), though, and arrive to the code cells, there is always the blue box around input-output.

[image]

Is there a way to hide or disable it in slideshow mode?

Or do I have to write everything in markdown somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Just export the slides to html using the no input option:

```
jupyter nbconvert YOURNOTEBOOKSNAME.ipynb --to slides --no-input serve
```

For more check out [nbconvert's documention](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-revealjs)